# Deriving conservation laws from stress-energy tensor

Tags: partial-differential-equations, complex-numbers, dispersive-pde

I'm going through Tao's book on nonlinear dispersive equations. In dealing with the Schrodinger equation 
$$
iu_t + \frac{1}{2}\Delta u = 0,
$$
he defines the stress-energy tensor in standard coordinates by 
$$
T_{00} = |u|^2, \ \ T_{j0} = T_{0j} = \text{Im}(\bar{u}\partial_{x_j}u).
$$
(Other components of $T$ are also given, but not really needed for my question.) He then says that the following conservation law follows by a direct computation: $\partial_t T_{00} + \partial_{x_j}T_{0j} = 0$ (here we are summing from $j = 1$ to $d$).

I have been working on this but am very stuck. From the definition of $T$ and the equation $u$ satisfies, we get 
\begin{align*}
\partial_t T_{00} &= 2uu_t = iu\Delta u \\
\partial_{x_j} T_{0j} &= \text{Im}(\partial_{x_j}\bar{u}\partial_{x_j}u + \bar{u}\partial_{x_jx_j}u) = \text{Im}(\bar{u}\Delta u).
\end{align*}
The last equality follows since the derivative commutes with the conjugate, and $\bar{z}z = |z|^2$ is real. But then, writing $u = u_R + i u_I$ in terms of its real and imaginary components, we have
$$
u\Delta u = u_R\Delta u_R - u_I \Delta u_I + i(u_R \Delta u_I + u_I \Delta u_R).
$$
Since $T$ is real, its derivatives are real-valued, and thus $iu\Delta u \in \mathbb{R}$. Therefore the real part of $u\Delta u$ is zero, and we're left with 
$$
\partial_t T_{00} = iu\Delta u = -u_R \Delta u_I - u_I \Delta u_R.
$$
But $\text{Im}(\bar{u}\Delta u) = u_R \Delta u_I - u_I \Delta u_R$. Then the sum $\partial_t T_{00} + \partial_{x_j}T_{0j}$ is $-2u_I \Delta u_R$, not zero, as desired.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated. I cannot see where I've gone wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can derive the conservation law

\begin{align}
\partial_t T_{00} &= \partial_t \lvert u \rvert^{2} \\
&= (\partial_t  u)u^{*} + (\partial_t  u^{*})u \quad (1) \\
&= \frac{i [ (\Delta u) u^* - (\Delta u^{*}) u ]}{2} \quad (2) \\
&= \frac{i \partial_{x_i} [ (\partial_{x_i} u)u^{*} - u(\partial_{x_i} u^{*})] }{2} \quad (3) \\
&= -\partial_{x_i}[\text{Im}(u^{*} \partial_{x_i} u)] \quad (4) \\
&= -\partial_{x_i}T_{i,0}
\end{align}

where we used

(1) the Leibniz rule

(2) the differential equation and its conjugate

(3) the fact that partial parts $\partial u \partial u^*$ cancel. Repeated indexes are summed (Einstein notation)

(4) $z-z^*=2i \text{Im}(z)$ for every complex $z$